# Ansible: specify instance profile with ec2_instance module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

In the older `ec2` module of ansible, there was the ability to set the `instance_profile_name` for the instance being created. (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html) Example:

```
- name: Create an EC2 instance
  ec2:
    region: "{{ instance_values['region'] }}"
    key_name: "{{ instance_values['key_pair'] }}"
    group_id: "{{ instance_values['security_group'] }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_values['instance_type'] }}"
    image: "{{ instance_values['image_id'] }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ instance_values['vpc_id'] }}"
    instance_profile_name: "{{ instance_values['instance_profile'] }}"
    assign_public_ip: no
    count: 1
    wait: yes
    instance_tags:
      Name: "{{ instance_values['name'] }}"
    volumes:
      - device_name: /dev/sda1
        volume_type: gp2
        volume_size: 32
        delete_on_termination: yes
  register: ec2_info
```

BUt the newer `ec2_instance` module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_instance_module.html) doesn't seem to have a field for `instance_profile_name` to be defined. This is a problem for us because we've defined our security for the server running our ansible that it cannot create instances (`RunInstances`) unless the following condition is met:

```
Condition:
  StringLike:
    'ec2:InstanceProfile':
      - 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:instance-profile/Thing1*'
      - 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:instance-profile/Thing2*'
```

So my problem becomes, if I can't define an Instance Profile on an instance I'm creating, I can't create instances at all with my ansible code. :\ Any ideas?

Comment: I believe the thing you want is [`instance_role:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_instance_module.html#parameter-instance_role)

Comment: @mdaniel Alas, that was one of the first things I tried. That's for roles though and not instance profiles, right? WHen I put the role arn in there I get the following: `An error occurred while searching for instance_role arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/Thing1Role. Please try supplying the full ARN.: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetInstanceProfile operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/Thing1Role' at 'instanceProfileName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\w+=,.@-]+`

Comment: When I try it with role NAME, I'm getting an error about not being able to GetInstanceProfile. I'm working to get those rights to try THAT.

Comment: I put in the instance-profile arn and I get that I'm not authorized to call RunInstances. The only reason I wouldn't be authorized is because of the StringLike of InstanceProfile in my OP. 

Still waiting on getting the correct rights to GetInstanceProfile to try it by name and not arn.

Comment: Yup, same issue even when I have GetInstanceProfile rights so I can put it in by name.

the `instance_role:` parameter is for a `role` not an `instance_profile`. So to aws I'm still trying to create an instance without an instance_profile, and my condition doesn't allow that.

There's GOTTA be a way to define an instance profile on a new instance in `ec2_instance`, right? I mean... otherwise that's a pretty big degradation in functionality from the older `ec2` module.

Comment: The [ec2 module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_module.html) module *does have* the `instance_profile_name`  parameter as shown in your question. But the link you posted for 2.9 is [ec2_instance module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ec2_instance_module.html).

Comment: @seshadri_c Right that's the whole gist of my question.  :D I'm trying to upgrade from ec2 module which is just in maintenance and uses plain boto, to the newer ec2_instance module that uses boto3 (long story, trying to solve a wholly different problem)